# How to shuffle data in an order where 1 data is used more than once using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

Let's say I have this arraylist ["a","b","c","d"]
I want to display
a-6 times
b-2
c-4
d-1

I want to show these in another arraylist in a specific order
But should not come the same element next to eachother except at last

Can you help me write this algorithm?

Example of the output:
a b c d  a b c  a c  a c  a  a

Comment: You'll learn a lot if you find a solution by yourself, the time you invest solving problems like these will help your mind find patterns for more complex stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check performances here https://jsfiddle.net/7vsgxyde/. 6 times faster than [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803681/1636522), 12 times faster than [User633183](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54835972/1636522). Modern JavaScript is sexy but use it carefully :-)

```js
function roundRobinRepeat(elems, repeats) {
  var l = repeats.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
  var w = Array(l), i = j = r = 0;
  while (i < l) {
    if (repeats[j] > r) w[i++] = elems[j];
    j = (j + 1) % elems.length;
    if (j === 0) r++;
  }
  return w;
}

console.log(
  roundRobinRepeat(
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
    [ 6,   2,   4,   1 ]
  ).join("")
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  roundRobinRepeat(
    [{id:1}, {id:2}],
    [2, 3]
  )
));
```

It's quite hard to explain with words, so I leave you a trace of execution. I hope you don't mind :-|

Initialization (`l` means "length", `w` means "word"):

```
elems = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
repeats = [6, 2, 4, 1]
l = repeats.reduce((x, y) => x + y) // = 6 + 2 + 4 + 1 = 13
w = Array(l) // = [empty × 13]
i = j = r = 0
```

Iterations (`r` means "round", `i` and `j` are indexes):

```
while (i < l) {
  if (repeats[j] > r) w[i++] = elems[j];
  j = (j + 1) % elems.length; // 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, ...
  if (j === 0) r++; // 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...
}
```

```
 j | repeats[j] | r | take |  i | elems[j] | w.join("")
---|------------|---|------|----|----------|-----------------
 0 |          6 | 0 |    y |  0 |      "a" | "a"
 1 |          2 | 0 |    y |  1 |      "b" | "ab"
 2 |          4 | 0 |    y |  2 |      "c" | "abc"
 3 |          1 | 0 |    y |  3 |      "d" | "abcd"
---|------------|---|------|----|----------|-----------------
 0 |          6 | 1 |    y |  4 |      "a" | "abcda"
 1 |          2 | 1 |    y |  5 |      "b" | "abcdab"
 2 |          4 | 1 |    y |  6 |      "c" | "abcdabc"
 3 |          1 | 1 |    n |  6 |      "d" | "abcdabc"
---|------------|---|------|----|----------|-----------------
 j | repeats[j] | r | take |  i | elems[j] | w.join("")
---|------------|---|------|----|----------|-----------------
 0 |          6 | 2 |    y |  7 |      "a" | "abcdabca"
 1 |          2 | 2 |    n |  7 |      "b" | "abcdabca"
 2 |          4 | 2 |    y |  8 |      "c" | "abcdabcac"
 3 |          1 | 2 |    n |  8 |      "d" | "abcdabcac"
---|------------|---|------|----|----------|-----------------
 0 |          6 | 3 |    y |  9 |      "a" | "abcdabcaca"
 1 |          2 | 3 |    n |  9 |      "b" | "abcdabcaca"
 2 |          4 | 3 |    y | 10 |      "c" | "abcdabcacac"
 3 |          1 | 3 |    n | 10 |      "d" | "abcdabcacac"
---|------------|---|------|----|----------|-----------------
 j | repeats[j] | r | take |  i | elems[j] | w.join("")
---|------------|---|------|----|----------|-----------------
 0 |          6 | 4 |    y | 11 |      "a" | "abcdabcacaca"
 1 |          2 | 4 |    n | 11 |      "b" | "abcdabcacaca"
 2 |          4 | 4 |    n | 11 |      "c" | "abcdabcacaca"
 3 |          1 | 4 |    n | 11 |      "d" | "abcdabcacaca"
---|------------|---|------|----|----------|-----------------
 0 |          6 | 5 |    y | 12 |      "a" | "abcdabcacacaa"
```

Comment: I want to get the data here through a JSON how can I do that?

Comment: I meant just parsing a JSON string . a,b,c,d,..and its times repeating

Comment: ['+
                    '{"id":"1","name":"a","duration":"5","times":"6" },' +
                    '{"id":"2","name":"b","duration":"7","times":"2" },' +
                    '{"id":"3","name":"c","duration":"9","times":"4" },'+
                    '{"id":"4","name":"d","duration":"12","times":"1" },'+
                    '{"id":"5","name":"e","duration":"5","times":"5" }]}';

Comment: @EmmaScarlet `var input = '[{ "id":"1", "name":"a", "duration":"5", "times":"6"  }]'; var data = JSON.parse(input); var elems = data.map(x => x.name); var repeats = data.map(x => parseInt(x.times, 10)); var word = roundRobinRepeat(elems, repeats);`.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate an array with the count and take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and iterate until no more elements are available.

In `map.forEach`, the key is pushed to the result set and a check is made with the decremented count, and if it is not zero, then this new `count` is set to `map`.

Otherwise the entry with the actual key becomes deleted. This reduces `map.size` as well, which indicates the count of elements in `map`.

```js
function spread(array) {
    var map = new Map(array),
        result = [];
    
    while (map.size) {
        map.forEach((count, key, m) => {
            result.push(key);
            if (--count)
                m.set(key, count);
            else
                m.delete(key);
        });
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(spread([['a', 6], ['b', 2], ['c', 4], ['d', 1]]).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive approach that isn't concerned with indexes or other intermediate values -

```js
const puzzle =
  ( [ x, count = 0 ] = []
  , ...rest
  ) =>
    count === 0
      ? rest.length === 0
        ? ""
        : puzzle (...rest)
      : x + puzzle (...rest, [ x, count - 1 ])

const result =
  puzzle (["a", 6], ["b", 2], ["c", 4], ["d", 1])
  
console .log (result)
// abcdabcacacaa
```

And a slight variation that might make it a little easier to see what's going on -

```js
const puzzle =
  ( x
  , count = 0
  , ...rest
  ) =>
    count === 0
      ? rest.length === 0
        ? ""
        : puzzle (...rest)
      : x + puzzle (...rest, x, count - 1)

const result =
  puzzle ("a", 6, "b", 2, "c", 4, "d", 1)
  
console .log (result)
// abcdabcacacaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/54835972/1636522. Interesting algorithm but quite slow, even slower than Nina https://jsfiddle.net/7vsgxyde/ :-\ Anyway, the following version is more readable in my opinion, at least for beginners.

```js
function puzzle (x, count = 0, ...rest) {
  if (count !== 0) {
    return x + puzzle(...rest, x, count - 1);
  } else if (rest.length !== 0) {
    return puzzle(...rest);
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

console.log(puzzle(
  "a", 6, "b", 2, "c", 4, "d", 1
));
```